# Should these sexually suggestive jokes be kept or deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There are a few jokes in "[Do good math jokes exist?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist)" that I think are inappropriate.

Specifically:

- [Nov 21 '09 at 9:01](https://mathoverflow.net/a/6360/5736) item (1)
- [Oct 19 '09 at 16:03](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1229/5736)
- [Dec 10 '09 at 23:14](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8496/5736)
- [Dec 15 '09 at 1:31](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8931/5736)

All of these are jokes about people's bodies (mostly women's bodies) with sexual implications. In short, this is website is a professional environment, and these jokes are inappropriate for a professional environment, so I think the jokes should be removed from this website.

Now, you might wonder: "Why, exactly, are these jokes inappropriate for a professional environment?" Honestly, I'm not able to explain it exactly. What I know is that in my experience, people often feel excluded by jokes like these, and when asked why, they usually provide good reasons. Hopefully someone else can explain it better than I can.

Besides, "sexually suggestive remarks" are explicitly against the [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

So, what should we do about these?

---

I may as well mention the following jokes while I'm at it:

- [Dec 13 '09 at 7:32](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8738/5736) - This one uses a double entendre, albeit without any sexual implications.
- [Nov 4 '09 at 0:11](https://mathoverflow.net/a/4018/5736) - Gross-out humor.
- [Oct 21 '09 at 11:57](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/1636/revisions) - Toilet humor.
- [Oct 19 '09 at 12:04](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1203/5736) - Uses sexual slang.

Comment: I think the 2nd and 3rd ones on your list are pretty clearly inappropriate.  The others don't seem nearly as problematic to me as those two.

Comment: Given the question is a) closed as off-topic b) almost ten years old c) CW, I see little problem of removing entries that are considered inappropriate. They add no value to MO.

Comment: And in case it's not clear, I do consider the jokes in the first list inappropriate (and the second list more just childish or bad taste; I personally wouldn't miss them if they went)

Comment: Let me address the four jokes you mention first: (1) why do you think a stripper has to be a woman? (2) the joke is about mini-skirts and the "philosophy" (if you will) behind it, there's no mention of a woman or a woman's body, although I agree that this may not have aged well. (3) Yes, that's not a great joke. (4) I don't see the problem here, to be honest. Now, there's something to say about "keeping it professional", but if MO is like knocking on a colleague's office for a question, I don't see why a bit of blue humor is necessary bad, as long as nobody is offended [...]

Comment: [...] and by that I do mean to exclude people who are offended for the sake of taking offence. Of the jokes you mention, I can see which might be considered offensive ("a hot chick" seems to me like it is the problem), but the others make no assumptions on gender, personality, race, or any other group of people. So unless someone wants to point at a specific reason why a group of people is to be offended by that, I'd consider this fine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Given the cultural context in which these jokes arose, it is clear that they refer to women rather than men.  Why bother defending them?  I would think very poorly of a colleague who made sexually-tinged jokes at work.  We should just delete these answers.

Comment: @Andy: I guess we come from two different cultures, then. But then again, I am sure that there are people who think poorly of me for cussing often (especially when political topics are brought up). And then again, I tend to think poorly on them. The circle is complete, the student has become the master, etc. etc. My point is, I guess, that I am not trying to defend those jokes. I am rather pointing out that it might be over-sensitivity. And for what it's worth, we can't whitewash the past just because we're uncomfortable with it. Instead we should use the past as motivation for improvement.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: "Whitewash[ing] the past"?  Really?  These are hardly examples of important historical documents, or even "edgy" political speech.  These are just stupid and juvenile jokes, completely unrelated to the purpose of this website.

Comment: "And for what it's worth, we can't whitewash the past just because we're uncomfortable with it. Instead we should use the past as motivation for improvement." Well, perhaps improvement can be achieved by deleting the jokes?

Comment: I have hesitated to post this comment for fear of being inflammatory.  If the moderators want to delete it, I'll understand.  But the original (pre-editing) version of this post contained a sweeping and unsupported generalization about the sorts of people who would make these jokes --- a generalization that  I (and I am sure  others) found pretty  offensive in its own right.  There is, of course, an argument to be made that the responses to the post should be based primarily on its content and not its motivation.  But I think that the lamentable motivation should not be completely ignored.

Comment: How many male strippers does it take to change an abelian grape?

Comment: @Gerry: Two. One at home, and one at work. (See, the grape is commuting.)

Comment: As I see, the question has [historical lock](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/1083/revisions). This means that - unless the lock is removed - the answers cannot be edited or deleted by regular users.

Comment: I challenge the assertion "This website is a professional environment.", and suggest that a different basis be picked for deleting part of the post.  While I do not encourage further additions to the (historical) post, this post represents part of what MathOverflow was; removing parts of it may encourage something worse coming back, or even more history being removed.  Gerhard "Unsure Where Traction Is Here" Paseman, 2019.08.02.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman The WayBackMachine exists to keep historical records. The live site, in my opinion, should represent the current consensus of what's on-topic on the site, and shouldn't really include things that are off-topic today (even though they were on-topic at the time).

Comment: I  think the Wayback Machine should not be relied upon for an archive, and that today's community (as well as yesterday's and tomorrow's) should shoulder the responsibility for archiving this forum.  I also think the community has little consensus on most subjects related to the forum, apart from no spam and not much homework and try to keep the level of math high (and what level that averages out to is also unknown).  If we don't have clear reminders of what is off-topic today, what can we point to demonstrate something off topic?  Gerhard "Most How To's Aren't Read" Paseman, 2019.08.02.

Comment: @AsafKaragila and Gerhard: I value the continued existence of the site - and my personal hope that it remains more like a resource of the form "ask your colleague down the hall, except in this case no such person exists in your department" rather than a gamified Wikipedia - more than attempts to preserve the tone and foibles from 10 years ago >

Comment: > also, I don't recall if, at the time, I said on http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussions/ that this question should be closed on grounds of general lameness (not blue humour, just intrinsic lameness) but that seems like an attitude I might have taken >

Comment: > and so it feels like the best resolution is to just delete the whole question, perhaps archiving the comment on some affiliated site if one feels strongly that Gedaechtniskirche serves a purpose here. There are more important issues of free speech to defend, perhaps in views expressed during actual answers to actual mathematical or academic questions, than the right to have a departmental lounge where one can drink and smoke. Yemon "If We Fight Like Animals, We Die Like Animals" Choi

Comment: @YemonChoi: I've deleted my comments and will speak to Asaf about it more privately.

Comment: Will we see censorship of mathematical terms coming, too? E.g. "handlebody" clearly has sexial connotations, by the same token as "Moebius stripper".

Comment: @AsafKaragila MO is not really like knocking on your office neighbor's door; it's more like knocking with thousands of people watching. You can use four-letter words in a private conversation, moderating their use as seems fit, but I don't think you would use them here because you know very well that lots of people find that distasteful (and they *will* be flagged and removed). "As long as nobody is offended": No doubt that many women (and some men too) are offended, but far fewer have the audacity to say so -- many will try to shrug it off, with a mixture of irritation and resignation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not to pile on, but I'd like to echo Todd's comment while also admitting (if Todd and Noah are reading) that _in private joking with friends_ I would use rather different language than I do on here, and that is because I know what will and won't offend friends, and what will and won't get taken personally.

Comment: @ToddTrimble In the interests of balance, I'd have to admit that I have several friends in the maths community of varying gender, ethnicity, nationality, and socio-economic background, who would probably lean towards Asaf's expressed views on what is and isn't funny / acceptable; and some others who would lean towards Noah's, but by no means a clear majority either way

Comment: Tanner: espite my expressed views that it might be best to delete the whole of the original MO question/post, I must be honest and say that at heart I subscribe to the Mel Brooks philosophy https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/21470-tragedy-is-when-i-cut-my-finger-comedy-is-when -- you may say that this has nothing to do with the "sexually suggestive" aspect that you highlight in the title of your own post/question, but I would argue that (a) comedy is transgressive, either against mores or against rationality (b) in settings where transgression can cause offence, let's not bother with the comedy

Comment: To be clear, I’m not even objecting to most of these jokes.  I don’t think MO is a good place for collecting jokes, but if someone were hosting a collection of math jokes somewhere else, I would only object to the 2nd and 3rd.  I respect the opinion of someone who objects to all of them (which is part of why I think MO shouldn’t be collecting jokes), but my opinion isn’t “dirty words are only allowed in private” it’s that the 2nd joke is really bad in public or in private.

Comment: @YemonChoi "that _in private joking with friends_ I would use rather different language than I do on here" ... me too, and really that's my entire point. In private with people I know well, I may use pretty coarse language, but in public I would certainly avoid that and I think that's appropriate. This point seems so utterly obvious that I'm have difficulty understanding a backlash to preserve certain sex jokes with more than a little wink-wink nudge-nudge element to them, in a public forum ostensibly dedicated to professional interests.

Comment: I'll add, also for the sake of balance, that one of the best (or at least highly upvoted) jokes I ever made on MO was just a *bit* off-color, and I admit I'd sorta be sad to see it deleted. [I won't say what it was, but I think it'd be a stretch to consider it anti-woman.]

Comment: @ToddTrimble going out on a limb here, but I think it perfectly possible that for some (for many?) going on MO is a chance to let one's hair down, blow off steam, and feel part of a perceived or actual counter-establishment "samizdat" community ... So perhaps the downvoters of Tanner's question, and some of the commenters, are reacting against what they see as someone coming into _their_ "space" and laying down rules. (I also have theories about geography here)

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, MO contains multitudes. Internally what I keep coming back to is what it might feel like being a woman reading stuff like this (cf. Elizabeth Henning's comment under one of the posts we're discussing). According to many women these sorts of little incidents are pervasive and oh so tiresome that a certain degree of fatigue sets in; Izabella Laba once wrote a long and eloquent screed on why she's not interested in MO. I'm not completely deaf to PC concerns, but I also think takes little effort to see the problem with some of these posts. Take it on a case by case basis.

Comment: @Todd, I admit that I did not see Elizabeth's comments under that answer. And after reading them, I agree that that joke should probably be deleted. And while yes, we don't complain about s%#t problems in every f^#@king thread, I think that a thread about jokes is perfectly fine if the jokes are off color, or off colour I guess.

Comment: Links [two](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1229/5736) [three](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8496/5736) [four](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8931/5736) seem to point to the main question, rather than to any particular answers.  Have the answers been removed?

Comment: @ToddTrimble, I was interested to read Izabelle Laba's [post](https://ilaba.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/why-im-not-on-mathoverflow) ([and](https://ilaba.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/still-not-on-mathoverflow)), but I couldn't find anything by Elizabeth Henning in a quick browse, or even by [searching](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=Elizabeth+Henning).  Could you link to the comment you [mention](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4307/should-these-sexually-suggestive-jokes-be-kept-or-deleted#comment20687_4307)?

Comment: @LSpice I have posted the comment you're asking about [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51286748#51286748).

Comment: Closing questions as "opinion-based" seems like an odd thing to do on meta.

Comment: @LSpice, they must have been deleted, since the given times do not appear in the list when you sort the answers by "oldest".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed. -- And I think the combination of closing a question as "opinion-based" and taking concrete actions on the basis of it or triggered by it seems particularly weird ... .

Comment: @LSpice yes, deleted. As a 10k+ user I can still see them.

Comment: I see now that my first comment was somehow removed, without my consent. I don't know if this was a moderator acting on someone's flag, or if it simply was flagged by a few people and got deleted automatically. In either case, I am saddened to see my opinions removed in this way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila For what it's worth, I thought your comment seemed reasonable, and I definitely didn't see anything offensive or unhelpful about it. I'd be happy to see you re-post it as an answer instead of a comment, if you like.

Comment: I'll mention that the post has now been deleted. Perhaps this is not the end of the story, but I think now we can reset the counter and that this current meta post can also be deleted. If anyone wants to weigh in within the next 24 hours for some concluding remarks, go ahead.

Comment: @Todd: Why are we deleting *this* thread?

Comment: @ToddTrimble Users below 10k cannot see this - so I just want to ask whether it was deleted by regular users voting to deleted the question or whether it was a moderator action. (And I'll add that I also consider deleting the discussion on *meta*  rather unusual suggestion - I think that it's better to keep relevant past discussions rather than hiding them and leaving them displayed only to a fraction of users.)

Comment: @Martin: Todd cast the final deletion vote.

Comment: I think deleting the question is an even bigger mistake than deleting the part under discussion. It feels like removing this meta question is a bigger mistake still. I wonder what will be deleted (and then forgotten or covered up) next.  Shout out to @Asaf for trying to preserve rather than erase.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I'd like to point out that since a moderator has cast the final vote to delete, regular users cannot vote to undelete. Also let me point out that at the time the final vote to delete was cast, the question had 4 pending votes to reopen.

Comment: Okay, I'm listening. Mine was the 10th vote to delete, and to be honest I forgot the aspect that Stefan pointed out -- mea culpa. I take back the proposal to delete this meta post.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your first comment was flagged as rude/offensive, and I agree with that assessment. If you think your defense of the miniskirt joke is worth preserving, you are welcome to expand on your ideas with a blog post somewhere.

Comment: @S.Carnahan:  For the vast majority of us, I would imagine that inclusivity as well as tolerance of other viewpoints are both important virtues, and the difficult bit is about how to balance them.  In this context, I find removing Asaf's comment as offensive puzzling.  If I remember correctly, there was nothing rude in what he wrote, and I don't even think he defended the Bourbaki joke.  I recall that he pointed out jokes 1 and 4 as being not obviously sexist.   The discussion is about whether these jokes are offensive or not; how can Asaf's opinion on that be  disallowed?

Comment: @S.Carnahan: I wrote to Noah in a private email. I did not defend the second joke. I pointed out that it does not read to me as sexually offensive in any kind of way. I *know* that moderating a sensitive topic is hard, I do. But I would appreciate if you don't dismiss me to a "blog somewhere" if I have a different opinion and a different point of view. What about the comments that blatantly call me a sexist? Are they not rude towards me? I don't see you telling those people to blog about it somewhere else.

Comment: It is good that these matters are being considered seriously, but we're treading a very fine line between moral idealism and censorship here -- deleting Asaf's comment on a meta thread seems to cross that line. As a <10k user who's just entered this discussion I've been censored from even seeing Asaf's comment to evaluate its contents; it's just gone. I was able to infer from the [...] in his second post that I'd missed something, but I know less about his position than I would otherwise (and it would be easy to assume he defended the second joke if he hadn't clarified above).

Comment: @Alec, 10k has nothing to do with it. Once a *comment* is deleted, you can't see it no matter how many points you have.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: I find it quite insulting that not only you reacted the way you did, but despite several people (other than me) criticising your behavior, you decided that it is not important in any way to defend your actions. I suppose that you may have blogged about it elsewhere? May I have the link?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Since you feel so strongly about this, I've undeleted your comment for now.  Would you care to explain your defense of the miniskirt joke?  To me, it appeared to be a disingenuous deflection, basically "why ever would you be offended if this precise word doesn't appear?" when the context makes it rather obvious.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: Thank you. Let me clarify now, I am not "defending" that skirt joke. It wasn't particularly funny, but it also reflects how skirts were seen at the time. It did not age well, yes, with that I agree. And as I wrote Todd, I did not see Elizabeth's comments when I wrote mine. I certainly support that being deleted after seeing those. But at the end of the day, I didn't read this joke as sexual, or as demeaning to women. And perhaps that is a cultural thing. And this whole gang up that happened on this page feels like enforcing Americanism on people who are not from the US. [...]

Comment: [...] And at the end of the day, to me that is just as bad as sexist jokes. But maybe that's because I am not from the US, and I don't think that the culture in the US is so great that we need to follow its example. So let me repeat what I said, again, I am not defending that joke, nor I have defended that joke. I also didn't feel that this joke is made to sexualize women or their bodies (maybe I have seen a lot of men wearing skirts recently too). I do agree, however, that the joke *should* be deleted, after seeing Elizabeth's comments on it. If that's defending, maybe I'm using English wrong

Answer (score 42):

I wanted to say specifically why the second joke on the list really should be deleted.  There's a very common trope in math where people analogize math to an attractive woman often explicitly in a sexual way.  I've seen this happen in talks.  I once saw it happen in a talk where the person illustrated the point with a photo.  This is all really deeply inappropriate and people need to stop.  The analogy in that joke only works if the listener thinks of themself as staring at the woman, and completely fails if the listener thinks of themselves as the one wearing the skirt.  And it's not just a one-off joke, it's a common trope that's really problematic and puts women graduate students in a terrible position when people make this kind of analogy in public.  Having it here, especially with it highly upvoted, especially with people writing defenses of it, especially with it coming from a famous mathematician (of sorts), is continuing the culture that says that it's ok to make analogies between mathematics and attractive women, and that's not ok.

Comment: If you upvoted this comment consider flagging the relevant answer.

Comment: "...the culture that says that it's ok to make analogies between mathematics and attractive women, and that's not ok." Is making analogies (or similies) between music and attractive women OK? Asking for Irving Berlin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pretty_Girl_Is_Like_a_Melody

Comment: If you're a professor of music composition, yes it would be inappropriate to explain the concept of a melody by using an analogy to what parts of a woman you find most attractive.  If you're writing a pop song about what you find attractive in women, then that's entirely different.  This shouldn't be very difficult to understand.  I'm not objecting to "The Math of Love Triangles."  I'm objecting to people sexualizing their explanations of math concepts.

Comment: I accept your distinction between giving a class on music composition and writing a pop song. Isn't there a distinction between giving a math talk and posting to an MO thread on jokes?

Comment: I'll agree that it's *worse* in a math talk.  At any rate, the context here is not harmless.  It's a quote which is used in an article to illustrate the way a prestigious and powerful group of exclusively male mathematicians talked about math among themselves in a sexualized way.  It's not a coincidence that there were no women in Bourbaki.  I guess inviting a woman would have spoiled the fun of constantly making bawdy jokes about women's bodies while talking math.

Comment: As the guy who defended the joke* ten years ago, I have to say that I understand this explanation and I agree with the delete.

* But not sexualization of mathematics.

Comment: While I agree with many of your points about inappropriateness, I yet again find myself taking issue with your mind-reading skills. People in different places & in different times & in different contexts think differently from people you might think they resemble now. " I guess inviting a woman would have spoiled the fun of constantly making bawdy jokes about women's bodies while talking math" seems to be putting cart before horse;- Bourbaki's failure to invite women was prob. a symptom of other things & their sense of what was appropriate humour was a symptom of absence of women, not a cause

Comment: Yes you're certainly right that the causation goes both directions.  At article length and not comment length I'd have put more nuance into that phrasing.

Comment: [deleted a comment which evinced the same carelessness that I have been prone to criticize in others]

Comment: You might want to have a look at the article, you can judge for yourself whether my summary is fair.  (The author certainly phrases it more dispassionately and academically than I did, but I don't think I've misread the point.)  https://www.jstor.org/stable/301970?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @NoahSnyder yes I belatedly looked at it, which is why I retracted one of my comments; but I think I still stand by my earlier comment

Comment: If I could edit comments outside of the 5-minute window I'd happily rephrase that last sentence.  I'm somewhat hesitant to delete the whole comment just because I could have phrased one sentence better.  But I take your point.

Comment: @NoahSnyder you should read some Susan McClary - a feminist professor of musicology who has written that at one point in Beethoven's 9th symphony " the carefully prepared cadence is frustrated, damming up energy which finally explodes in the throttling murderous rage of a rapist incapable of attaining release." People who live in glass houses, or ivory towers, etc...

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.  Think about the situation you're putting rape survivors in if you put in a brief unsupported rape analogy in your argument.

Comment: (Important caveat, of course if you're teaching about gender and sexuality you have to discuss sex in an academic context.  I would have no problem with someone giving students a paper assignment about the relevant paragraph of *Bourbaki's Art of Memory* during a course on the history of mathematics that included a month on the history of gender and sexuality in mathematics.)

Comment: But I think it's telling that your one example is 30+ years old from a book I'm reasonably confident you've never read (I'm happy to be corrected if I'm wrong).  I've heard men make analogies about math and attractive women at least a dozen times in the last decade or so.  If this "joke" were a one-off that wasn't part of a larger pattern among mathematicians then my opinion would be a lot less strong, though I'd still think it wasn't a great story to tell.

Comment: @alephzero Out of interest, as someone whose account says that you've been on this site for 5 months, and as someone who doesn't appear to have posted on it, what exactly is your interest and your relevant experience on how a site for research mathematicians and their community should moderate its content?

Comment: Some of this is stuff is quite disturbing, I have to admit I was not really aware of the extent of this due to the fact that I studied originally online and have not been to that many academic talks.  This is quite troubling though.

Comment: For example, there is the famous case of the Cox-Zucker machine, where a male mathematician takes a concept from mathematics discovered by two male mathematicians and then turns it into a lewd joke for the benefit of other male mathematicians and sniggering material for male mathematics students.  I think this stuff has to stop, and maybe wouldn't even mind if the concept was re-named.  I also have heard people in my office making lewd jokes of this kind, this is a bit troubling.

Comment: The most famous analogy between mathematics and a beautiful woman I can think of is Edna St. Vincent Millay's 1922 poem "Euclid Alone has Looked On Beauty Bare".  I don't have a good sense of how it would come across today, in the situation Noah describes.

Answer (score 13):

Now that this meta question exists, I wonder if an alternative to deletion could be to edit the jokes in question to remark that they could be considered offensive, and to add a link to this meta question.

There is a slight but IMO important distinction between making a joke [in anger](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/do-use-something-in-anger), and quoting a joke in response to a request for math jokes.  For example, a list of jokes that are widely regarded as inappropriate, but nevertheless were highly upvoted, can be a useful resource for people who are trying to fight sexism and need to convince skeptics who deny that there is a problem.  I'm not saying we should go further and specifically ask people to come up with offensive jokes, but given that some questionable jokes were suggested, it seems to me that there is some value in keeping them around, as long as they are accompanied by some indication that the community recognizes that they might be objectionable.

Comment: Actually I see now that someone else has made this suggestion, but as a postscript to an answer that seems to have been highly downvoted for other reasons.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit 3:** I'm not sure why I didn't think of mentioning this before I made a mess of things, but there is already a standard way to deal with answers and questions that are rude or abusive, namely by flagging them as such.  This method does not require any moderator intervention to yield concrete results.

**Edit 2:** I have undeleted the answers for now, and I am sorry for taking such abrupt action without waiting for any consensus to take shape.  As Lucia pointed out in the comments, even if voting to delete is not an option, flagging a joke for moderator attention is a good way for members of the community to communicate their specific opinions.

**Edit:** Sorry, I had forgotten about the negative score condition!  Thanks to Federico Poloni for reminding me.  Okay, I've unilaterally deleted the last three from each list.  I welcome additional community feedback.

If an answer is borderline, I am in favor of erring on the side of deleting, because the cost of one person feeling marginalized seems to far outweigh the benefit of one person enjoying a few more jokes on a site whose real purpose is sharing and answering precise mathematical questions.

**Old answer:** I agree that some of the answers are rather inappropriate.  It is not clear that we have a consensus about precisely which ones we should delete, so I do not want to take any unilateral deletion action.  Fortunately, we have a standard process for this: people with enough points have the power to delete bad answers.

I had put a lock on the question last year, mostly because people had been making occasional trivial edits to answers, bumping the question to the front page.  That lock is now removed, so the usual deletion method can move forward.

Comment: Note that, as far as I understand, people (with 20k+ reputation) can vote to delete only answers with score -1 or less. So, for instance, a necessary condition for the first example to be deleted with the normal process is that it gets downvoted by at least 88 different users beforehand. (And, on the other hand, its score means that at least 87 people in the past have found the answer OK and upvoted it.)

Comment: I'm a little confused, as it seems that you did in fact unilaterally delete most of these answers not long after you posted this statement of your intention not to do so.  Did something change in the interim?

Comment: Regarding  the cost-benefit analysis in the second paragraph, you seem to have omitted the cost of a great many people feeling marginalized by having their upvotes ignored.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Are you making your claim seriously and in good faith?  It seems unlikely to me that more than a handful of the people who voted on an answer to an off-topic community-wiki question would care enough about its deletion 9 years later to feel marginalized.

Comment: Scott: Yes, I am making my claim seriously and in good faith.  I did not upvote any of these jokes, and I can't imagine any circumstance in which I'd want to.  But I nevertheless feel personally offended that other people's upvotes are being ignored, and if I can feel offended on their behalf, then I think it's not a big stretch to think that some of them might feel offended on their own behalves as well.

Comment: Scott:  I am also offended, like @HarryGindi , at the fact that this action is being taken at the behest of someone who is not an active member of the community, and who told us explicitly in the first version of his post that he was motivated by a pet psychological theory about what's wrong with the people who posted these jokes.  I am offended that such behavior is being rewarded.  So if you're counting the taking of offense as a cost, please add my feelings  to your balance sheet.

Comment: I will add here that, given the opportunity, I think I'd have voted to delete a few of these --- but in this no way diminishes my unhappiness at the way this came about and the way it's being handled.

Comment: It may sound like someone who is not part of the community, but the user page of the question's original poster shows some contribution away from zero.  If there are ten community members in chat concerned about this issue, let their voices be heard in meta as well.  I appreciate Scott Carnahan's disclosure, but feel that his action was premature. I hope he can undo it. I hope also more of the community responds.  Gerhard "Other Expression Forms At Risk" Paseman, 2019.08.02.

Comment: Fortunately for this issue, I've avoided having a career. If the people who are upset want to stay silent themselves then **** ****.  I care enough about this forum to voice concerns similar to that of Steve and of Asaf.  If a member speaks out on the issue of the care of this forum and their career gets a hit because of it, we should be aware of that too. Gerhard "It's Bigger Than It Seems" Paseman, 2019.08.02.

Comment: While some of the deleted responses were no great loss, it still seems preferable to obtain a consensus from the MO community rather than proceeding unilaterally.   Currently, this question has 13 votes in favor and 11 against -- this seems hardly conclusive.  I understand that one cannot vote to delete the problematic answers -- but people could be asked to flag them for moderator action, and if there are enough users who do that (adjusting for number of upvotes of the relevant answer) then it would be entirely appropriate for the moderators to delete.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Thank you for letting me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @Steven and Harry, I do feel guilty about the role that I played in making you (and, it sounds like, several others) upset. I don't know of anything I can say that will make the situation better and not worse, which is why I haven't really said anything beyond my original post.

Comment: @S.Carnahan :  Thanks very much for listening.

Comment: @Tanner, I think you have a valid concern, but (in my opinion) your rationale for the concern is not good enough as a basis for action. If the community says collectively "We don't need these anymore", then the bad jokes will be deleted.  I think they are needed, and that their deletion should be even more carefully considered. Gerhard "Bad Examples Also Have Purpose" Paseman, 2019.08.02.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Yah, I worried about this, but failed to follow up on it. There's also the issue of my referring both to "their behalf" and "their behalves" in the same sentence; surely this can't be right whether or not "behalves" is a word.

Comment: @Lucia Could you say more precisely what "adjusting for number of upvotes of the relevant answer" should mean? The miniskirt joke has more than 50 upvotes, but I am not comfortable seeing if 50 flags accumulate before taking it down.

Comment: @ToddTrimble:  Hi Todd, I don't quite know -- you guys are the moderators!   Roughly what I had in mind was something like the delete process, which requires more votes depending on the number of upvotes.  As a first thought, something like 3 flags to start with, and then adding extra flags at the ratio of 20 upvotes to 1 (I believe this is the ratio for deleting questions), which would suggest something like 6 flags for that answer?

Comment: @ToddTrimble:  I think (although I'd disagree) that one could reasonably argue for ignoring the upvotes and taking unilateral action. I also think one could reasonably argue for holding the equivalent of an election.  But I don't think one could reasonably argue for holding the equivalent of an election augmented by a weighting scheme chosen ad hoc  to insure a pre-determined outcome.  (I'm not saying you've proposed this, but I think some of the discussion has come perilously close to it.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble :  As an appendix to my above comment, I want to make it clear that I agree that several of these jokes don't belong here, but am mildly uncomfortable with the idea of overruling so many upvotes, and far more uncomfortable with the idea of doing so in response to a post as inflammatory as the one that triggered all this.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I've read the post several times, and saw the retraction and edit too. Do you find it still inflammatory?

Comment: @ToddTrimble :  Yes, but only because I'm aware of the history.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Okay. The only thing I'd add is that Tanner did apologize as well, and there's not much more he (I'm pretty sure "he") can do at this point. But anyway I think we may be inching along to some semblance of consensus, at points. (By the way, I'm not going to be applying any pre-set algorithm; just use my judgment in determining any action to be taken.)

Answer (score -6):

There are established mathematical terms which may be construed as to carry sexial or drug/alcohol-related innuendo. Examples:

1. handlebody
2. pipe dream
3. drunkard's walk
4. perverse sheaf
5. [Tits alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tits_alternative)
6. [hairy ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) theorem

Should MO start censoring these and similar established terms, too?
IMHO, word play in some of the cited in the question jokes is quite similar, e.g. "Moebius stripper".

---

PS. I do not advocate lewd jokes, I merely want to point out that we are on a slippery slope in this thread.

---

PPS. Deleting several years-old answers is an attempt to rewrite history; I'd rather see these answers commented as "examples of inconsistent application of website policies, disapproved". Or perhaps screened away as "sensitive/offensive content", so that an extra click is needed to see them.

I discussed this question with a female CS professor, and her remark was that MO should not resemble a male sauna in its tone. That is to say, an overload of these sort of jokes might be too much for some to bear.

Comment: To be honest, I've never particularly liked the last one, because it's often paired with a 'wink wink, nudge nudge'. But finding coincidental homophones from other languages amusing/offensive (as in 5.) reminds me of some kids in my first German class at school where we learned the noun 'der Vater' (worse: Whakatane, New Zealand, which has an unexpected pronunciation)

Comment: When correctly viewed/Everything is lewd. (Tom Lehrer, Smut)

Comment: Do I really need to say that MO has no plans to censor terms established in the literature? What we're primarily discussing here are (IMO mostly lame) jokes that are intentionally sexually tinged. I don't think any of the terms you mention fall under that category, and honestly I find this a little alarmist in tone.

Comment: (Alas, if the Moebius stripper joke-maker had instead started with "Why did the chicken cross the Moebius strip?", then we wouldn't need to have this conversation!)

Comment: @user131781 - I tried to keep straight face while writing this...

Comment: @Todd: We wouldn't need this conversation because *that* joke would suck and there was a consensus for deleting it? Or maybe because it wouldn't be flagged as "sexually suggestive" or otherwise "less professional"? Maybe we need to work it out with a pencil... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actually, the chicken version is there in the thread :-) And also, I heard that it was in Big Bang Theory. So I guess it was already field tested. :-)

Comment: @Todd: Some offense to the writers of TBBT, it sucked when it came to actual nerd culture. It mainly reinforced outdated stereotypes. You can't claim that the mini-skirt joke is offensive to women, while defending TBBT with a smile.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not defending... just stating the facts ma'am. :-)

Comment: @Todd: It was field tested as crap, that's what. Because the majority of science jokes in TBBT were crap that was passed as "LOOK! SCIENCY WORDS!"

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay, Asaf. I'm really not defending TBBT, honest.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I do think it's telling that you get irate at TBBT's misrepresentation of "nerd culture", but are seemingly ok with jokes premised on sexism and the objectification of women.

Comment: @Andy: Please don't put words in my mouth. I never said that I am okay with sexist jokes or with jokes that objectify women. It's your pregoretive to think this way, of course. But you'd be in the wrong. While you're washing your hands from any past misdeeds don't forget to wash Frege off you, as well as Einstein, and might as well wash von Neumann too. Of course, you'd say, one can appreciate their scientific contributions while critiquing their personal choices. But I guess I'm not allowed this freedom...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The point of the last part of your rant (the one involving a list of famous mathematicians) eludes me.  I've said what I think needs to be said.  Given all you've written, there is enough material for other people to draw their own conclusions...

Comment: @AndyPutman would this not be better done with private communication?

Comment: @Andy: I have no interest in trying to change the opinion of someone who has made up his mind. Please leave me alone.

Comment: Late to the party, but what drug-related innuendo is there in "pipe dream"? Also, I have been unable to come up with any lewd imagery for "perverse sheaves", and it's not for lack of trying. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: @darijgrinberg - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_dream : "Wild dreams induced by inhaling from an opium pipe".

Comment: @darijgrinberg - people in this thread are triggered by words such as "stripper", "backside", etc - surely "perversion" can't be good either in their view...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Thanks! Now I finally get what this word means. (For some reason I thought pipe dreams referred to malfunctioning explosives, perhaps due to the semantically equivalent but not etymologically cognate German word "Rohrkrepierer".)

Comment: While I'm sure you know this and were being facetious, let me emphasise that there is nothing even remotely suggestive about the '[Tits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Tits)' in 'Tits alternative'.

Comment: @LSpice: What about Tits Buildings? Or as they are known in Norwich "American style table dancing"?

Comment: Pipe Dream is referring to 1990ish minigame: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_Mania

Comment: @Noah thanks for the memories!

Comment: Interesting, now even this is proposed to be deleted. Would the people who voted this be deleted please explain why? Is my point, that one should not edit history, irrelevant?

Comment: [GLAVLIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Directorate_for_the_Protection_of_State_Secrets_in_the_Press) seems to be alive and kicking...

Comment: Please don't delete this.

Comment: I agree with @ToddTrimble (GLAVLIT seems strong; maybe MASSOLIT if one perceives a "herd" effect? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_and_Margarita )

Comment: BTW, Dima, I suggest reverting your edit. I do actually understand your frustration and I would certainly oppose any move to delete this answer

Comment: @Todd: In spirit of moderator intervention, you can delete and undelete to nullify the delete votes...

Comment: @ToddTrimble - please feel free to undo my last edit.

Answer (score -13):

Just delete the entire question.  It’s already closed as off-topic, it’s not what the site is for.  There’s no good reason for it to still be there.

Comment: I actually think this would be a less divisive course of action than selective deletion of a small number. (Note that I am still not commenting on the rights or wrongs of people's assertions in the comment thread to this meta question)

Comment: @YemonChoi: Yeah that's basically my point in suggesting this.  I mean of course we're going to all disagree about exactly what the line is for what jokes are appropriate, that's why MO shouldn't be in the business of collecting jokes.

Comment: It's a bit unclear if you're proposing for the moderators to delete the question, or for users to vote to delete it.  The first seems problematic to me in this case, and the second can be done anyway (and might indeed be the best solution).  In this case, I think it would take 10 votes to delete the question (because of its popularity), and that would seem fair.  (Of course 10 people could then vote to undelete if they felt strongly in the opposite direction ...)  Personally, I think OP unnecessarily opened up a can of worms -- a ten year old question with no new activity or interest.

Comment: @Lucia: Good point, I was imagining the mods do it, but I think you're right it's simpler for users to just vote to delete.  I've gone ahead and put in my vote (though I'm sure if it's closed that vote will get reversed).  I also think you're right that this meta thread was counterproductive, it just encourages people to write defenses of the jokes which is worse than the existence of a closed question.

Comment: Personally, I like many of the jokes that are in the answers to that question. I would hate to see them all gone just because four out of 87 answers are questionable.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Can't they be archived on tea? We could keep all of them and a mod note could be added at the start saying "this is historical material, does not reflect the views of the mods, etc"

Comment: Also someone who wants to curate jokes about math could set up their own site for it.

Comment: @NoahSnyder Indeed. (Though see my comments on the main thread if you want a truer reflection of my actual views on humour)

Comment: @YemonChoi Can't they be archived here on the main site, where they were originally posted, with the same disclaimer? What's the difference? Or maybe find a solution just for those four posts?

Comment: I still don't believe it.