# Catering to professional appearance a bit much?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deletions

*[In case of hurry, please scroll down to the suggestions at the very end.]*

The deletion of [the Math Jokes thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist) (mirrors: [html](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/msed/mathjokes.html) or [pdf](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/msed/mathjokes.pdf)), most likely provoked by [the meta.MO debate about some specific jokes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4307/should-these-sexually-suggestive-jokes-be-kept-or-deleted?cb=1) but not supported by a majority of users, appears to be at least the second time that MO moderation decisions are being based on the perception of outward appearance. (The first, at least to my knowledge, was the deletion of a question about "what image epitomizes mathematics to you" after [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scream) became the highest upvoted answer.)

There are good points to be made against having threads like this on MO; I agree with what seems to be the consensus about them, which is that these are bad questions, relics of a bygone age when MO was still figuring out what it wanted to be. The march of science would not be impeded if they had never been asked.

However, deleting them, in my opinion, requires better reasons than not starting them in the first place. Worse yet is my impression that the deletions are motivated not by pondering what would make MO a better forum but by an (implicit, yet rather transparent) desire to appear maximally professional, polite and smooth to the outside world. And this is not a great goal to set -- even if I assume that outside appearance is nearly as important a goal as inside usefulness (full disclosure: I don't), I believe it is too deceptive a light to steer our ship towards. Consider the likely effects of the deletion of the jokes thread: The jokes thread is no longer publicly visible. But [the question debating the appropriateness of the sexual jokes therein](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4307/should-these-sexually-suggestive-jokes-be-kept-or-deleted?cb=1) remains visible (it's on meta, so there is far less grounds on which it could be deleted). Everyone who cannot see deleted threads is likely to conclude, on the basis of their priors and political leanings, that

- either some really creepy jokes have stood undisputed on MathOverflow since 2009,
- or MathOverflow has succumbed to outside pressure on a current moral panic and deleted a whole thread based on a few risqué posts.

Either of these paints MO and its governance in a worse light than the thread itself. Meanwhile, no one has stepped in to claim any actual damage from any of the deleted answers. The main forces behind the deletion seem to be "these jokes are unprofessional" and "no one cares for this thread anyway". But the slope is slippery, since we have now set an expectation that even theoretical concerns about unprofessional-looking posts will be met with deletion. Next time it may well hit closer to home, and eventually we'll **have** to respond with "thanks for your concerns, but our core community believes them not strong enough to delete useful content". The later this happens, the bigger the resulting shitstorm and outrage. In some circles, it is best to never become a fellow traveler, lest you become a traitor once your paths split.

What I've said before is not particularly novel and I expect disagreements to be at where to place our red lines rather than whether there should be any. But with too many different red lines, we'll eventually see the window of conversation narrow even further, since it is easier to get a question deleted than to get it undeleted (math.stackexchange is currently having [a similar problem](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30163/can-we-please-stop-closing-and-deleting-old-posts-with-answers) for other reasons). Thus, in the interest of common ground, here are some **specific suggestions:**

1. Content that appears to be useful or interesting to a reasonable number of mathematicians (witnessed, e.g., by 10 upvotes, by 5 upvotes and appreciative comments from established users, or by citations from published literature) is not to be deleted barring very grave and specific reasons (e.g., passwords being leaked).
2. Full thread deletion is to be reserved for threads with no redeeming value whatsoever. Answer deletion is to be reserved for answers that are so bad or unredeemable that downvotes and comments of disapproval don't help.
3. Vague notions like "professionalism", "appropriateness" and "inclusivity" are not to inform moderation decisions until made precise with more specific arguments. Non-CW posts are to be understood, first and foremost, as statements by their original authors, not as manifestations of the "spirit of MO" whatever it might be; they are furthermore not understood to be targeted at any specific reader unless visibly declared to be targeted. Posts should not be judged on how they would look like if ripped out of context and addressed to someone they were never written for.

Feel free to comment and improve on these points. I regard upvotes as "I agree with the general idea and at least 2 of the 3 suggestions modulo minor issues" and downvotes as "this is going in the wrong direction". Eventually, we'll see if these concerns are worth separating and voting on.

Comment: I don't see much evidence behind the rather strong "Everyone who cannot see deleted threads is likely to conclude..." claim.  For example, a reasonable alternative explanation would be "There was an old closed post that people mostly ignored, but after it became the subject of discussion, 10 people with enough points decided it wasn't worth keeping."

Comment: @S.Carnahan: This thread [has been referenced multiple times](https://www.google.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmathoverflow.net%2Fquestions%2F1083%2Fdo-good-math-jokes-exist&oq=https%3A%2F%2Fmathoverflow.net%2Fquestions%2F1083%2Fdo-good-math-jokes-exist&aqs=chrome..69i64.294j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and even the meta discussion at some point observed that one of the answers in question had 88 upvotes. The internet doesn't forget that easily.

Comment: "are motivated ... by [a]... desire to appear maximally professional, polite and smooth to the outside world" -- you don't know that's the motivation of the 10 individuals who voted to delete.

Comment: That's right, Darij doesn't know. Just like I don't know that MathOverflow is being influenced by Social Justice Warriors with no regard to the community at large.  But that is how it appears to me with the deletion of the question. And this is not the first episode to suggest that to me.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I don't know for sure, but I'm making conclusions based on the lack of other arguments presented in the meta thread. Claims of harm and exclusion have not been underpinned with evidence; a general dislike of the thread has been stated multiple times, but not confirmed to be a majority opinion; the very poster who started the thread has responded with bewilderment that it had the unintended effect of disappearing the whole question. This is supposed to be one of the most transparent places on the internet; if you have better reasons, do tell!

Comment: Let me ask a question. If the 10th and final vote to delete the joke thread were made by a normal user, would you have created this post?

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Probably yes, since I have actually (mis)used the word "moderator" in the meaning of "20k+ user". However, in a way, the fact that the final vote was from a ♦ moderator makes the problem worth: it prevents undeletion by regular high-rep users.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I already admitted in the other thread that unfortunately I forgot this fact. Just like I usually do when I cast a vote to close a question at main, I wait until four others have voted first and then vote last (except in cases where closure seems utterly inevitable), so that my own vote is weighted like every else's. When I saw nine votes to delete, I followed that same modus operandi, but as I say I forgot about the prevention of undeletion. If we put that aside however, I would view the 10 votes as a normal democratic outcome.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Even in democratic outcomes, it makes sense to ask about purposes and consequences and whether the former could be attained in a different way avoiding the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, Darij. I would also say that "prompt deletion" is inaccurate. The joke question was actually controversial back in 2009, and the more recent discussion played out over some time; I held back from saying anything there for quite some time, and the votes to delete (prompted no doubt by the discussion) trickled in slowly. Anyway, saying "prompt deletion" creates an appearance that various parties acted rashly and dictatorially, and what with accusations of SJW being flung around, adding fuel to the fire, this doesn't seem quite fair.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I'd just like to point out that there are no "don't delete"-votes, and that we cannot know how many people would have voted in that direction if that possibility would exist. -- So without the possibility to vote for undeletion at least after the thread had been deleted, I'm not sure how deletion can be seen as a democratic decision of the community here(?)

Comment: Hey Stefan, I think this point has already been mentioned before. I am saying **if** it were a normal user casting the 10th vote, then that would be democracy in action. I have already conceded that it was unfortunate that I had forgotten about the effects of my vote.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Removed the word "prompt", which wasn't load-bearing or particularly precise. It seemed prompt to me, since it happened 2 or so days after I first saw the meta discussion. Whether one ascribes the decision to SJW influence or to an obsession with professional appearance or to embarrassment over bad humor is perhaps a question of one's prior experience with MO, since very few of the delete voters have taken part in the discussion; the one similar situation that I personally remember was the Scream deletion, so I homed in on the second option.

Comment: Thanks for that edit. In general, here at meta it would be much,much better to keep one's ideas (projections?) about the motives of others to one's self -- and stick to assertions that can be backed up with evidence. This meta post seems to some degree based on assumptions about motives, especially your point 3. And just as no one is obliged to explain a reason to vote to close, I don't think it's wise to set up a system where people are obliged to explain a vote to delete.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: If motivations cannot be discussed, then decisions cannot properly be analyzed. My impression is that the whole deletion system was originally intended for dealing with (literal) spam, and set up accordingly (thus the ease of deleting and the lack of feedback mechanism). But it is now being used for quality control and occasionally, as it seems, for public image management; I don't believe this should be done with the same automatism and lightness as deleting spam. I don't think anyone should be strictly *obliged* to explain a vote, but in case of important votes like this, ...

Comment: ... it is definitely legitimate to ask for reasons, and if none are given, to question the extent to which the moderation team and the whole 20K+ subcommunity act in the interests of the site.

Comment: For what it's worth, even though I am very much against the deletion of the thread as a whole, and even some of the jokes mentioned in the other discussion, I can completely understand where the moderators deletion is coming from. Sites like MSE, and I guess also MO, work well when there is *less* controversy. If certain questions become highly controversial, an action is needed to remove that obstacle. This can be locking as "historically significant content" or mod-deletion. But some action needs to take place. [...]

Comment: Well, Todd -- such things can happen, and actually there is not much lost by that. -- Since (in contrast to close-/reopen votes) a user can immediately cast another delete vote after a thread has been undeleted, to undo that small mistake, it would suffice to undelete the question to restart the decision process. -- Then the people who voted to delete can vote to delete again, and once the question is deleted, others can vote to undelete if they wish so. -- Or are there any issues with this approach which I don't see?

Comment: [...] If something is considered offensive to a large enough demographic, I understand why the instinct is to delete it. And even if I disagree with the deletion, I get why it happened. I would have opted, personally, to locking the thread and deleting the more contentious jokes. But that requires more time and effort, and I see why someone with a diamond would just delete it and get it done. But I am not even sure that I am supposed to participate in this particular discussion, it's not a blogpost somewhere... :-P

Comment: "stood undisputed" is a really weird description of an answer whose second comment was someone criticizing it as sexist which had 68 upvotes!

Comment: @NoahSnyder: But that's not visible from the meta discussion when the thread itself is deleted!

Comment: FWIW, I think my vote to delete was pretty well explained in the various comments I left. I understand if people disagree with me that deletion was the "least wrong" option, but I just wanted to point out that this was not an impulse decision. I think I was the 6th or 7th vote to delete, and these votes did not start until some time after the original question; debate was already going on before you happened to look at the meta question, Darij

Comment: It's also worth noting that, beyond the comments here and on meta, there were flags on some of the answers, only visible to moderators. As well as @NoahSnyder's example of the highly upvoted comment criticizing one answer as sexist, some of the flags also disputed the appropriateness of the posts.

Comment: The moderation process is simply not going to be a purely public process, and for delicate issues there is always going to be an internal discussion amongst the moderators, parallel to the public discussion here on meta. It's always been this way, and at least I think it's mostly worked. There was clear consensus amongst the moderators that eventually this question needed to be removed.

Comment: @ScottMorrison: That's sad to hear. If it was limited to the jokes thread, I wouldn't care much, but I highly suspect that this non-public moderation process will be exploited to get rid of other material in the future, material which is more on-topic and substantial than a list of jokes. After all, it seems that one moderately popular meta thread started by any outsider is sufficient to cause deletion (and if it fails, one can try again, with other arguments), while undeletion is essentially impossible unless moderators team up. I would love to be disproven on this prediction.

Comment: @ScottMorrison: I still don't understand why my comment had to be removed, and even less why the moderator who removed it decided that it's appropriate to tell me that if I want to express myself I should do it elsewhere. The next step is to tell me to write my answers on some blog post, and the step after that is simply to suspend me altogether. And I know it sounds exaggerated, because it is, and I don't expect anyone to think this way. But it sort of kinda feels that way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, sorry, I haven't followed the details of that comment being deleted. I don't think you should be encouraged to post your arguments or criticisms elsewhere, but rather that they should be welcome here (on meta). Obviously there are some strong disagreements occurring in this thread, but this is what meta is for.

Comment: I want to register my dissapointment that the whole question got deleted (instead of the offending answers, which would have been ok by me) and also that @ToddTrimble cast that last deletion vote thereby preventing undelete votes (which I tried to cast).

Comment: Amusingly, the system allows one to cast a Reopen vote but not an undelete vote.   So the jokes question is now open (and I guess people can vote to close!) while it is still deleted!

Comment: Noted, Felipe. Since you address me, it seems you want me to respond. How many times do I need to say that I inadvertently overlooked the mechanism? But -- on discussion about this with the other moderators, it was agreed that the question needed to be removed anyway. See one of the earlier comments by Scott Morrison.

Comment: I went through the top 200 highest voted questions on MO (the jokes question would have been one of these).  I think of all of these, the jokes question had the least to do with research math or the practice of math, and I guess was the least suited for MO.  So upon reflection, I think this question was quite an anomaly, and deletion (leaving aside all other issues) was the right call.

Comment: @Lucia: I mostly agree with this; I don't mind the deletion of the jokes thread nearly as much as I'm worried about the precedent it sets (if not in the eyes of the mods, then at least in the eyes of outside critics, who are not likely to grasp the details and will assume they now have a veto on discussion). What I'm trying to do here is set some principles that will ensure that deletions will remain restricted to exceptional cases like this. Unfortunately, at this point I'm not sure whether the moderators are placing the distinction in the same position as me. For illustration, consider ...

Comment: ... the following critiques a concern troll could lob at **mathematical** answers: (1) An answer mentioning "MacMahon's Master Theorem" should be revised in terms of the connotations of the word "Master". (2) The use of "men" and "women" in [matching-theoretical metaphors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Application_to_marriage) is outdated and exclusionary. (3) The "Carroll determinant formula" should be renamed due to [strong evidence for its author's pedophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Carroll#Controversies_and_mysteries). Each of these claims ...

Comment: ... I can easily see bolstered with a breathless article in Slate, HuffPost or Breitbart, rallying twitter tough guys to bark Godwins every time someone links to MO. Where do we draw our lines?

Comment: @Scott: Yes, that's what meta is for. Unless of course someone disagrees with you and perceives your words as offensive enough to merit deleting them in a manner that also elicit a rude response from the moderator involved.

Comment: @StefanKohl FWIW I left comments suggesting deletion of the whole jokes thread, and I am not a moderator, nor am I USian in background. Once again, I respect the POV that the thread should not have been deleted, I just want to counteract any narrative that the action was _solely_ the work of a clique

Comment: I still haven't understood exactly what the view of the moderators is: is the deletion of that question (A) the autonomous and final decision of the moderators, after sufficient discussion and input from the community, or (B) something that the community should decide on, and may override by voting? I think that this is an important point to clarify here.

Comment: I understand your post as saying that once the censorial wheels are in motion there is no stopping them. I don't think this is a problem of proper guidelines moderators should adhere to. It should be obvious that deletion of a question is a last resort and only applicable in rare cases, where the topic really does not contribute to the mathematics related elation of the readers of MO (i.e. why on earth delete jokes??). Rather it is about caving in to a mob of "children" who are unable to simply not read, watch or listen to things they don't like, but instead have a need to censor it.

Comment: @santkerheboln I don't think labelling (or guessing) that people who object to the original joke, like Tanner (or Noah, or Scott) are a mob of "children" is either fair or productive. Their argument, which you may or may not agree with, is that certain content was of a kind that is known to be offensive in other contexts and that leaving it on MO implied a social sanctioning of such content. I am happy to believe them if they say that their comments or actions were taken for what they thought was in the best interests of the MO site

Comment: @santkerheboln slightly off-topic, but 'It should be obvious that deletion of a question is a last resort and only applicable in rare case" may reflect the fact that, due to the reputation barrier, you can't see the questions which are deleted, which are mainly bald requests to solve homework, with a few known persistent cranks. In particular, my impression is that most of the questions which are deleted have nothing to do with any perceived controversy or censorship of dissenting opinions

Comment: @YemonChoi: You are arguing that the deletion of the jokes thread is atypical and should be considered as an exception. The three suggestions I made in my OP were meant to enshrine this somewhat, to ensure that the exception doesn't become the rule. The responses from the moderators have done nothing to convince me that this deletion was truly exceptional. If anything, I have gotten convinced that there is a widening rift between moderators and heavy metaers on one side and the rest of the users on the other (my question here was mostly gathering downvotes until it became ...

Comment: ... hot enough to be linked on main MO, at which point it started its upwards trend). And while I think santker's "mob of children" is imprecise, I frankly don't see why what we have is any better (a mob of concerned grown-ups acting out substitute parental impulses to protect the innocent, fragile outsiders from the dangers of the seventh answer to an old closed thread). Ultimately, what we get is a leaky library, one I cannot rely on to keep knowledge around. The jokes thread itself was too tangential to be a fully-fledged canary-in-the-mine, but now the responses to my question here ...

Comment: ... have so far not produced any statement from the moderators that would place a separating hyperplane with the jokes thread on one side and mathematically relevant content that may trigger someone's offense detector on the other. So I am not buying the exceptionality, not yet at least.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: It is also neither fair nor productive to delete a decade old gem, without consideration of the community as a whole, based on the unreflected objection of one person. I also don't buy the "safety" and "welcoming" intention of such measures. Some users, born in countries where speech is routinely censored and where making a "juvenile" joke can land you in prison, are certainly not going to feel more "safe" and "welcome" on MO, when they see this kind of censorship in action. Let me just state that this is highly offensive to many users, myself included.

Answer (score 31):

I support Darij completely. I'll even go a bit further and say that any thread that stood open since 2009 until 2019 without any complaints or controversies is good enough to stand forever and I'd rather risk offending a few good people than letting the "social justice warriors" control the discussions in any way beyond politely voicing their suggestions now and then with which we can freely agree or disagree as a community. I personally have nothing against sexist jokes (as well as jokes about mathematicians, Russians, people above 6 feet tall wearing a mustache and carrying a waist bag at all times, or even direct personal jokes about myself) if they are sufficiently smart and funny, but I wouldn't regret their being gone either if people feel like they are bad taste. However deleting the whole thread with no possibility of reversal is way too much. The appropriate thing to do now, IMHO, is to uncast the final moderator vote and let the community decide either way by regular voting with whatever result emerges being final. By now there is enough publicity around the thread to be sure that most people who care either way will participate in that "tug of war".

The argument about "being welcoming to all" can be easily turned around any time. What attracts some people can repel the others and vice versa and I talk here exclusively about people with good intentions and ability to make valuable contributions to the site. What we should agree upon and enforce is some general standards of discussion and behavior, not the "admissible points of view, language, etc.". The latter, IMHO, should be governed by the common sense alone and one has to learn to live with the fact that the common sense is subjective and varies from person to person a bit though there are many common points like not being outright disrespectful without a good reason, trying to express yourself in a clear way, sticking to the point, etc.

As to the general question of what is a good/questionable/bad MO question/answer, it seems to me that it is also time and community composition dependent. However, no matter how the corresponding factors fluctuate and drift, it is never a good idea to behave like we live in Orwell's 1984 and try to rewrite the past every time our opinions or official policies concerning the matters undergo a change unless we want to end up with this site (or our historical reality) to be inhabited exclusively by comrades Ogilvy.

Comment: FWIW, even though I did vote to delete the whole thread (mainly because I mistakenly thought this might put an end to matters) I would be happy with the final moderator vote being reversed, if possible, if the votes of myself, Strickland, Rickard et al could also still stand

Comment: @YemonChoi: For what it's worth, there's no limitations on how long before you can re-vote to delete an undeleted post. I'm not suggesting we undelete to have it "deleted properly this time". Just as an FYI.

Comment: With the caveat that I don't fully understand the mechanics of "uncasting the final moderator vote," I will say that I like fedja's suggestion of undeleting the thread and then letting the community decide whether to delete the thread. Like some others, I'm slightly concerned about "ideologically-motivated deletions" (for lack of a better term), but I'm more concerned that the community can't undelete the thread now, simply because Todd Trimble did something that even he now acknowledges was a mistake. If that acknowledged mistake can be undone then I'm in favor of doing so.

Comment: On the technical issue of "reversing delete votes": the only way of undoing the moderator delete-vote would be to undelete the post, leaving it with *no* pending delete votes remaining. *However*, the users who previously voted to delete would then be able to so vote again: unlike close votes, delete votes can be cast on the same question by the same user multiple times in between undeletions. (cc @YemonChoi et al)

Answer (score 11):

Here are some comments on your suggestions and the topic in general:

1. Professional mathematical interest in a question or an answer might well be a good necessary condition for MO but it will not make a good sufficient condition.
   If the unprofessional content can be cleaned away easily, the posts can and should be edited.
   If it cannot, then deletion is a natural way to go.

   Losing joke questions or similar is not a real loss in my opinion.
   If serious mathematical content is removed, there is a reason to object.
   Jokes should be collected someplace else (if anywhere), and reputation earned from such posts is perhaps reputation that never reflected one's mathematical contributions.
2. If discussion arises on some post or thread and you think it is salvageable, I recommend going and salvaging it.
   Edit it to make it better.

   I have experience in looking at colleagues ending up at MO after a Google search and looking only at the text written there, completely ignoring votes and comments.
   MO is supposed to be a repository of useful knowledge, and having bad knowledge (e.g. blatantly false theorems) hinders such endeavors.
   Therefore bad content should be removed, not just voted down and commented on.
   What counts as bad is matter of taste and of never-ending discussion.
   I'd say unprofessional stuff is largely bad stuff (although content can be simultaneously interesting both recreationally and professionally).

   One possible criterion for badness is making MO look less attractive.
   We might have lost potential contributors who do not want to engage in such folly, or we might not have.
   And perhaps our serious content has some more weight if our content is highly curated.
3. Notions relating to the social aspects of the field of mathematics are always vague.
   That is the nature of non-mathematical things.
   If I were to conjure up a full definition of socially acceptable jokes in a math talk, I am sure examples would be found soon indicating misjudgments in both directions.

   MO posts are addressed to people online happening to read MO, not just the OP of each question.
   Assuming this reader is a professional mathematician in a related field, the text should be sensible and unoffensive.
   These readers will keep on coming in no matter how old the post is.
   Therefore it is of importance to curate older content as well.

Having a welcoming and accepting social environment is important for mathematics, and that is something I think MO should help build.
This social environment is largely global due to the global nature of our field, and MO is a global actor.
I strongly think that a lot of mathematical talent is wasted due to potential or existing mathematicians feeling unwelcome.
You are free to disagree.

Frankly, I don't think voting is an entirely appropriate approach to these kinds of things.
If three out of a group of four mathematicians agree to make personal jokes about the fourth one, it is not okay.
Yes, this is a true effect even with jokes that may look like harmless silliness to many — and happens frequently with the persons replaced by groups of people, with "personal joke" replaced by "joke about a (minority or weak) group".
Three losing the ability to make bad jokes is a far smaller loss than one feeling unwelcome.

Comment: ad 1. But the posts **were** deleted at first! For some reason, the thread still ended up gone too. I really don't see a good reason for that other than perceived embarrassment.

Comment: "If three out of a group of four mathematicians agree to make personal jokes about the fourth one, it is not okay." None of those jokes (talking about the 4-8 answers that were the original bone of contention, not the whole thread that ended up as collateral damage) was personal; the more wide-ranging and diffuse the target of a joke is, the less do standards about its offensiveness need to apply.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Fair points. I expanded the answer a little. (a) Embarrassment is actually a sound reason for moderation, as there is value in making the site look attractive for prospective contributors. (b) The example of four mathematicians needed a remark that I had failed to include. The same phenomenon happens with groups of people, e.g. with men making jokes about women. I just tried to give a minimal example.

Comment: I think the question I refer to the most is the urban legends one. And to me that is one of the most appealing aspects of MO. It's a sense of community. I don't see why we need to adhere so strictly to some rule that there cannot be lighthearted fun on the site (outside of comments, anyway).

Comment: *bad content should be removed, not just voted down and commented on* --- Uhm, no, that's the exact opposite of how Stack Exchange is designed. If people don't look at votes and comments and mindlessly accept what they read on the internet, that's their problem.

Comment: Also, "this is wrong so let's delete it" is a very dangerous view, in general. If something is wrong, it's better to challenge it openly and explain why it's wrong rather than censor it out of existence.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I have enough to deal with in the real world (some of it involving trying to broker truces) without spending time arguing with people on meta.MO about issues that can boild down to personal history, philosophy, ethics, (mis)understanding of the history of intelligentsia and academia on at least two different continents, etc

Comment: @FedericoPoloni There are sayings to the effect that BS (or even just muddled stuff) can take an order of magnitude more effort to refute/debate than to start. I am not in favour of people lobbing rhetorical hand-grenades into the (meta) MO arena just so can they indulge personal differences which have nothing to do with mathematics and the research activities/interests of mathematicians

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for making your proposal.  I see that you have put a lot of thought into it.  My counter-proposal (that I haven't specifically run by the other moderators) is that content on MathOverflow be filtered the way it always has been.  In detail:

1. Content that is research-level mathematics will not be deleted.
2. Content that is clearly not mathematics, or not research-level, may be deleted by users with lots of points and moderators.

Naturally, there are borderline cases, where people may disagree about whether something is on-topic or not, and those require further discussion.  Nobody seems to be claiming that the jokes thread is one of these cases.

One might ask, how would the existing method differ from the new proposal?  Under the new proposal, some off-topic questions with lots of positive votes, like "[Is there an image for you that epitomizes mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2437/is-there-an-image-for-you-that-epitomizes-mathematics)" and "[Work of future fields medalists](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24800/work-of-future-fields-medalists)" and "[What might extraterrestrial mathematics look like?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135833/what-might-extraterrestrial-mathematics-look-like)" would not be deleted, because someone might argue that they have redeeming value.  Indeed, some of them have such arguments in the comments.  I think these questions were mildly entertaining, but they ultimately do not belong on the site permanently.  Each of them, after some time in the sun, was rightfully deleted.

I think it is proper that the jokes thread follow this pattern - it's basically full of weak tea you can find elsewhere on the internet, it was only active during the first 3 months of MathOverflow and just sat around closed for the remaining 97% of our history, and the only reason it was still visible was that no one bothered to suggest deletion earlier.  I had locked it last year with a "historical significance" note, but that was mostly because at the time I didn't feel like dealing with an extended discussion about the merits of deletion.  I now see that that was a mistake, and that such a discussion was more or less unavoidable.

I understand that the sequence of events that led to the recent votes to delete was objectionable to some people, but I don't think that justifies undeleting a thread that doesn't belong here.

(Thanks to Martin Sleziak for the data explorer query that produced the deleted questions with positive votes.)

Comment: One of the votes to delete the "image" question came from ... darij grinberg.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: ... because the deletion of some of the most upvoted responses left behind a fake discussion with near-0 interesting (not just mathematical) content. Unlike the jokes thread, the content of the responses to the image thread was mostly hosted outside of MathOverflow, so little of value was lost. To me, the Skrik answer, with its upvotes, was the most valuable message of the thread; it showed a facet of mathematics that isn't already exposed to death in popsci books and press releases.

Comment: As for your proposal: I'm not opposed to drawing a clear line between mathematical and non-mathematical content and judging them on different rules. But (1) I'd then like a confirmation that mathematical content will **not** be removed on vague fears of impoliteness, embarrassment and disfavored political opinions (see the three hypothetical examples in my comments to the original question). (2) "Research-level" can be interpreted far too restrictively; many good questions could be posed as grad or even undergrad homework, with the appropriate hints (behold two of my most ...

Comment: ... popular answers: [a commutative algebra 101 proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76772/is-the-sum-of-two-prime-ideals-in-different-polynomial-rings-kx-i-and-ky-i/76775#76775) and [a representation theory 101 proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14514/how-big-can-the-irreps-of-a-finite-group-be-over-an-arbitrary-field/14516#14516)). While moving such questions to m.se sounds like a good idea, it is less likely to work than it sounds (first, m.se loves to delete questions for lack of context, which MO questions usually indeed lack; second, migration likely changes the URL, ...

Comment: ... but MO questions have often been cited in the mathematical literature by their URL). (3) There are several meta-mathematical questions on MO that have the potential to rustle some jimmies, yet convey genuine information and insight ([example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338607/)). I would really not want them to fall afoul of narrowly defined polciies.

Comment: @darij, I only see two responses (to the "image" question) that were deleted before the whole question was deleted, and I don't know which is "the Skrik answer" – no one with that username posted an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scream): "The Scream is the popular name given to a composition created by Norwegian Expressionist artist Edvard Munch in 1893. The original German title given by Munch to his work was Der Schrei der Natur (The Scream of Nature), and the Norwegian title is Skrik (Shriek)." So a reasonable guess is that darij grinberg meant this image. (I think I remember it in that thread - 10k+ users are in a better position to check whether this was indeed the case.

Comment: As an outside observer of the whole discussion, I'd just like to say that I really appreciate having a reaction from a moderator now. For a while, it almost seemed (to me) as if the mods had gone into hiding and were waiting the whole thing out after rather convincing concerns about the deletion had been raised.

Comment: @GerryMyerson iirc the Skrik answer (Skrik is the [name of the picture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scream)) was hard-deleted before MO became part of SE, so there might be no trace of it here, but I remember it. I think the post was saying "Most of the time this sums it up rather well".

Comment: @darij OK, so that was https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2437/is-there-an-image-for-you-that-epitomizes-mathematics/4020#4020 posted by user Autumn Kent, deleted by Todd Trimble who left the comment, "This answer is temporarily deleted because of some trouble in the review queue." I guess the trouble in the review queue never got resolved. The deletion took place 30 April 2016. I think MO was part of SE by then.

Comment: @darijgrinberg As I said in the post, mathematical content will not be removed.  However, if someone places content that violates the code of conduct in the middle of a mathematical response, any user with edit privileges should be welcome to make a change that doesn't detract from the mathematics.  I believe your points (2) and (3) are concerned with "borderline" cases, and as I said earlier, these may require discussion.

Answer (score -1):

So, I have to ask you something.

You say that we're "catering to professional appearance" and acting on "theoretical concerns about unprofessional-looking posts" without any "actual damage."

I don't think that's true. I think that jokes like this are actually harmful. I admit that I don't have the *best* evidence for this, but I have evidence. I've read articles and blog posts about dirty jokes in environments that are supposed to be inclusive. What do the articles say? The jokes are harmful. I've read anecdotes from women who've heard such jokes. What do they say? The jokes are harmful. I've read various pieces of material about catcalling, and what do they say? Catcalling is harmful. These jokes are thought of as inappropriate for "polite discourse," and why is that? The only reason I can imagine is because they're harmful. These jokes are against the Stack Exchange Code of Conduct, and why is that? Again, I presume it's because they're harmful.

Do I understand how these jokes are harmful? No, I don't understand it. I don't understand general relativity, either, but other people do understand it, so I defer to them when it comes to general relativity.

You, I assume, believe that these jokes are *not* harmful; otherwise, I don't know why you would argue against deleting them. But my question for you is:

What's *your* evidence?

I honestly want to know. I want your voice to be heard and I want your opinion to be treated with respect.

Comment: I would be happier if this were phrased as an answer rather than as an invitation to a continued exchange (just by removing the first paragraph and some of the closing sentences). I don't think the SE format works well for discussions, which is one reason why I rather miss what-at-one-stage-became-tea-dot-mathoverflow-dot-net.

Comment: Also ... I am uncomfortable with trying to figure out weighty questions such as personal ethics and political-philosophy-in-the-broader-sense on meta.mathoverflow.net. I would rather we focus on how we behave rather than what we believe. Of course Darij may actually disagree with the POV expressed in the previous sentence! so I am only speaking personally

Comment: @YemonChoi Well, my purpose in posting this *was* to ask the question. If there's a better place to ask the question, or if it would be better to just not ask it at all, I'm totally fine with deleting this answer.

Comment: One can agree, Tanner, that some of the posts in that thread were harmful, and were better deleted, while still maintaining that the thread as a whole was not harmful, and did not merit deletion. I think you may be missing that distinction.

Comment: Articles and blog posts are not evidence unless they provide any; by the same reasoning, DnD would have been a major source of societal decline in the 1980s and video games in the 1990s. The press is subject to hype cycles and operates with vague terms that it re-interprets at will in strategic ways; this isn't exactly new. Even assuming that the mere presence of risqué jokes in personal communication is harmful to women or other minorities concerned, the situation at hand (where the jokes are thousands of miles removed from their readers and not targeted at anyone in particular) is hardly ...

Comment: ... comparable. When I hear an actual criticism of the jokes thread coming from a woman who actually participates in MO rather than merely sniping from the side, I'll reconsider, but for now the situation appears rather disconnected from actual issues and opinions are falling more in line with how willing people are to believe in currently fashionable paradigms.

Comment: @darijgrinberg what about selection bias? Quite possibly there have been female mathematicians who might have participated, or participated more, were it not for certain things they found off-putting; didn't Elizabeth Henning leave a comment to similar effect? And I think it is somewhat closed-minded to dismiss people's concerns as "currently fashionable paradigms": you have _no idea_ of how my own views might have been shaped by things I observed and was angered by in 1996, 2000, 2010-12, ...

Comment: @GerryMyerson TBF I think Tanner was espousing exactly what you describe. It's people like me (well, about 7 or 8 other people like me) who thought that the thread as a whole should be deleted, in light of the arguments that have started

Comment: @YemonChoi: The numbers suggest specific data; maybe that would make a nice blog post. (I do suspect the things that have angered you in 1996 and 2000, at least, were more serious than innuendo in untargeted jokes... these were times when there were real fish to wry.) But the speculation that all women were hurt so much by the 4 joke answers that they didn't even feel welcome to comment on it appears to be essentially devoid of evidence (exactly one woman commented on exactly one of the answers, which is in my eyes the one truly problematic joke).

Comment: Please note that, pardon the repetition, we are still beating around the bush as to the question why the whole thread "had to" be deleted.